# Process exited with value 3221225477

Tags: c++, class, dynamic-arrays

I created a program that use a dynamic array.  It works, when i use my insert function and then i show the elements of the arrays, it show me all what i want. The problem is that at the end of the program it doesn't return with value 0, but it is blocked for a few second and say "Process exited with value 3221225477". What is wrong?

header:

```
#ifndef VETTORE_H
#define VETTORE_H
#include "regalo.h"

typedef regalo T;

class vettore {
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,const vettore&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&,vettore&);
    private:
        T *v;
        int riemp;
        int max;
    public:
        vettore();
        vettore(const int);
        ~vettore(){delete [] v;};
        bool full(){return riemp==max;};
        bool empty()const;
        bool inserisci(const T&);
        T& operator[](const int index);

};

#endif
```

cpp file:

```
#include "vettore.h"

ostream &operator<<(ostream& out,const vettore & v1){
    for(int i=0;i<v1.riemp;i++){
        out<<v1.v[i];
    }
    return out;
}

istream &operator>>(istream& in,vettore &v1){
    for(int i=0;i<v1.riemp;i++){
        in>>v1.v[i];
    }
return in;
}

vettore::vettore(){
    riemp=0;
    max=10;
    v=new T[max];
}

vettore::vettore(const int n):max(n),riemp(0){
    v=new T[max];
}

bool vettore::empty()const{
if(riemp==0){
return true;
}else return false;
}

bool vettore::inserisci(const T& n){
    if(max==0){
        cout<<"Inserisci il massimo di elementi del vettore: ";
        cin>>max;
    }
    if(!full()){
        v[riemp]=n;
        riemp++;
        return true;
    }else return false;
}

T& vettore::operator[](const int index){
    return v[index];
}
```

main file:

```
#include "vettore.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int riempimento;
    vettore vett(1);
    regalo r1("Alex",300,"quadrato");

    vett.inserisci(r1);
    cout<<"Gli elementi del vettore sono: \n";
    for(int i=0;i<riempimento;i++){
        cout<<vett[i]<<endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `riempimento` is not initialized.

Comment: You should add some member to `vettore` to return the # of items in the vector and use that in your loop instead of having a variable that externally has this value.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues in your code:

1. `riempimento` is not initialised so the for loop in main will perform an unknown number of iterations, likely more than the size of your vector. It would be better to expose the value of `riemp` from inside the vector and use that in the loop instead.
2. You need to implement the [rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), this isn't causing you a problem yet but will in the future if you copy your `vettore` objects.
3. If `max` is 0 when you call `inserisci` you prompt the user for a value of max, you don't check that `cin` succeeds and you don't reallocate `v` to be large enough to contain `max` elements.
4. Not a problem but `empty` could simply be implemented as:

   ```
   bool vettore::empty()const{
     return riemp==0;
   }
   ```

Comment: How can i expose the value of riemp inside the vector?

Comment: Add the following function to your vector class:  `int size() const { return riemp; }`

Comment: if i use that, it works but give me a warning saying "non static data member initializers only available with std=c+11"

Comment: @AlexV. either add "-std=c++11" to your compiler command line or initialise your variables in the constructor rather than when you declare them

Comment: `"non static data member initializers only available with std=c+11"` I don't see how you could have had that error. You must have done something different.

Comment: @drescherjm maybe i didn't fix right the initializing of the riemp.  Can you help me to expose the value inside the vector in the right way? if i add the size() function, how can i call the riemp?  if i use vett.size() it say that error.

Comment: ***if i add the size() function, how can i call the riemp?*** I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: ***if i use vett.size() it say that error.*** I don't see how it does that. There is no initialization with that.

Comment: Put: `int size() const { return riemp; }` in your header right after `bool empty()const;` then change `for(int i=0;i<riempimento;i++){` to `for(int i=0;i<vett.size();i++){`

Comment: @drescherjm i am sorry. i add the function, now in the main, i wrote:          
   for(int i=0;i<vett.size();i++){                                                              
   cout<<vett[i]<<endl;
}   is it right? it seem work but i am not sure is the right way to do that.

Comment: @drescherjm ok, thank you very much.  Just another thing, for be better: In my main i wrote: vettore vett(1),   but you said was better to not do that in the other comments, is better if i wrote max=1    and vettore vett(max) ?

Comment: @AlexV. those 2 statements are practically identical, I'd just use the first one